# How can I modify my Ghost.org blog's date format

Tags: html, date, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

My Ghost.org blog displays dates as:

> 04 Nov 2013

This is controlled in `content\themes\{theme-name}\post.hbs` via:

```html
<time datetime="{{date format="YYYY-MM-DD"}}">
    {{date format='DD MMM YYYY'}}
</time>
```

I want this changed to a different format, like `Wednesday, 4th November 2013`, how can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ghost uses Moment.js to output dates.

From their [display format documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) we can determine that:

- `dddd` can be used to output the full day name;
- `MMMM` can be used to output the full month name;
- `Do` can be used to output the date in `1st 2nd 3rd 4th...` format;
- `YYYY` can be used to output the full year number.

From this we can craft our desired date format in `content\themes\{theme-name}\post.hbs` using:

```html
<time datetime="{{date format="YYYY-MM-DD"}}">
    {{date format='dddd, MMMM Do YYYY'}}
</time>
```

> Wednesday, 4th November 2013

Comment: @starfry indeed I do, not sure how I managed that - I'm already linking to their documentation on the line below!